Fetch each user data from Firestore failed
I'm trying to fetch each user data from firestore based on the user login, between I'm using React Native and firebase.
Fetch code
const UserInbox = () => {

    const auth = getAuth(app)
    const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("reciepent","==", userData? auth.currentUser.email:'unknown'))
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    const [messageText,setMessageText]=useState("")



  
 

   const fetchData = async()=>{
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
       
            const list = [];
            if(user){
                await getDocs(messages)
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    const {userId,recipient,messageText} = doc.data()
                     list.push({
                        id:doc.id,
                        userId,
                        recipient,
                        messageText
                     })
                    
                    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                    console.log(doc.data());
                    setUserData(list)
                  
                });
               
            })
             } else{
               setUserData(null)
           }  
    })
    return () => unsubscribe(); 
}

When I replace this line:
const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("email","==", userData? auth.currentUser.email:'unknown'))

With this
const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("city", "==", "CA"))

The code is working and fetching according to the condition but when I change the where condition based on the current user login I got only blank screen no thing retrieve.


What is the value of auth.currentUser.email inside the query? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

the value is the user email, which means when the user login only data of that user be retrieved according to the where condition

Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Alright, thanks in advance

I did change the email into recipient in the query code as it is in the database but still not working, I'm still getting the same result blank. even I edit email in the question above into recipient

In that case, you should go ahead with further debugging to see why the data isn't displayed in the UI.

Thank you so much for your time and effort, it is working now as it is expected I just replace the state const [userData, setUserData] = useState ([ ])  into  const [userData, setUserData] = useState (auth) I really appreciate your help


When I replace this line:


const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("email","==", userData? auth.currentUser.email:'unknown'))

With:


const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("city", "==", "CA"))

The code is working and fetching according to the condition but when I change the where condition based on the current user login I get only a blank screen no nothing is retrieved.

What you get is the expected behavior. When you're using:
const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("city", "==", "CA"))

It works because the document that is shared contains a field called city that holds the value of CA:

So the first query doesn't work because there is no email field present in the document, but only a recipient field that contains an email address. So you either change the query to use the recipient field:
 const messages =  query(collection(db, "feedback"), where("recipient","==", userData? auth.currentUser.email:'unknown'))
 //                                                                                         

Or you add a new email field inside the document that contains the email of the authenticated user.
If the ID of the document is the UID, then a simpler way of reading the document would be to create a document reference that points directly to the document and not perform a query.

Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
